# How do I share my Careers 2.0 CV or profile?

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs

This is the link in browser address bar when I click on my profile.
http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/edit/76545#

Should I share that link or there is another way to get the link to your profile/cv?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can share your Careers 2.0 profile by making it public. Going to your profile page, on the right hand side you will see a link named "Privacy Settings":

> [image]

These should be public. If you click on the link, it will take you to your privacy settings page where you can change your setting.

> [image]

Under Public Status, enter a custom URL at which you want your profile to exist and click on the orange "make my profile public" button. Then you can share your custom URL for people to visit.